# Enabling EditText OnClick when it is already disabled

Tags: android

I've noticed that I cannot use the `EditText.setOnClickListener()` when `EditText.setEnabled(false)` has been called before.

Is there any way to enable the `EditText` after clicking on it?

Answer (score 0):

By calling `EditText.setEnabled(false)` you are disabling the EditText So what will you do by implementing `EditText.setOnClickListener()`, You can't do like this

```
public void setEnabled (boolean enabled) --
```

Set the enabled state of this view. The interpretation of the enabled state varies by subclass.

See the official Docs --

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setEnabled%28boolean%29

If you want to use `EditText.setOnClickListener()`

then write `EditText.setEnabled(true)` before `EditText.setOnClickListener()`

Comment: Nothing i just thought there is a way to do that, cause i like the way `EditText`s become of color gray, so ill just change the color to gray on lost focus this is why i wanted to change it to read only.

Comment: No it will be grey because it is disabled now and if you want to use it why are you disabling it.